# Will a facebook user ID ever exceed JS Number.MAX_VALUE?

Tags: javascript, facebook

```
Number.MAX_VALUE == 9007199254740992
```

In other words can I rely on

```
var max = Number.MAX_VALUE;

if (fbUid > 0 && fbUid < max) console.log("valid fb uid");
```

I want to perform a check before I use it in FB.api()

Comment: Why are you checking to see if it's less than the max?

Comment: There has to be a range of valid fb uids, I don't know what the range is, so maybe doing it like this can make sure the fb uid is a valid uid. I can choose a different max, I don't know, that's why I'm asking.